# What is the difference between "could they have had" and "would they have"?

Tags: tenses

1.How many days of vacation **could they have had**?

2.How many days **would they have** on vacation?

if any...
thanks:)

Comment: There are two differences: *could* is not the same as *would*, and *days of vacation* is not the same thing as *days on vacation*.

Answer (score 1):

I think the first sentence is asking about how many days of vacation were possible, while the other is asking how many days were going to happen in a specific scenario. when someone wants to know how many days they could have had, they want to know how many opportunities the family received to be on vacation, expressed in days obviously. On the other hand, someone asking how days they would have had is basically just asking for an educated guess on how many days the family spent, presumably based on given information. The 2nd variation is often used hypothetically. In short, could is about what is/was reasonably doable, while would is about what is/was most likely done if the given requirements were/are met.

These are some random examples:

"If Astrid were more honorable, would you still have killed her?"

"How much could you have won?"

I hope this gave you somewhat of an idea when to use the 2 different sentences. I know this is poorly explained, and wordy.